# Consective character checker

Tags: java

I have written this code so far to check if the string has consecutive ascending or descending characters.
These are the invariants which mark the input has consecutive or not 
a String like 89012 or
xyZabc will count as consecutive. On the other hand 09283dgdDDf does not count as being consecutive.
Corner case such as AbCBa or 1abC should return false. On the other hand DcbaZ should return true

Note that my code is just for the character part so far, Please help this noob out to make it work. I have errors

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class generalizedorder {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        java.util.Scanner reader = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
                 System.out.println("Enter the string");
                 String s = reader.next();
    }
public boolean checkForAscendingOrDescendingPart(String s, int l)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= s.length() - l; ++i)
    {
        boolean success = true;
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        for (int j = 1; j < l; ++j)
        {
            if (((char) c + j) != s.charAt(i + j))
            {
                success = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (success) return true;

        success = true;

        for (int j = 1; j < l; ++j)
        {
            if (((char) c - j) != s.charAt(i + j))
            {
                success = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (success) return true;
    }
    return false;

}}
system.out.println(checkForAscendingOrDescendingPart);

}}
```

Comment: Why would "`String like 89012 or xyZabc will count as consecutive. On the other hand 09283dgdDDf does not count as being consecutive.`"???

Comment: @peeskillet maybe because having a "0" after the "9" or a "a" after the "z" is a simple "overflow" while "928" is cleary not consecutive?

Comment: @dognose Sounds right. I was confused what OP was trying to do

Comment: alphanumeric strings do not count. xyz is consecutive and abc is consecutive too thats why

Answer (score 0):

I did the following assumptions (from your description):

- 89012 - is consecutive because of "012"
- xyZabc - is consecutive because of "abc" (not "xyZ" - case sensitive)
- 09283dgdDDf - is not
- AbCBa or 1abC  - are not (why? - case sensitive PLUS assuming minimum 3 consecutive chars.)
- DcbaZ - is consecutive because of "cba"

So, you could do it by iterating from start to end, taking the `n` maximum allowed consecutive appearances into account and doing a simple calculation:

Characters beeing consecutive having an ASCI Difference of "1". (either negativ or positive).
Since you want to renter "abc" and "cba" as consecutive, the common thing is: The Sum of their ASCI-differences will be 2 or minus 2. If you want to go with "4 chars", the sum would be 3 or minus 3.

- ab -> max ASCI-Difference: `1`
- abc -> max ASCI-Difference: `2`
- cba -> max ASCI-Difference: `-2`
- abcX012 -> max ASCI-Difference: `2`

So, you don't want to hit `|n-1|` when comparing for consecutive chars, where `n` is the maximum allowed appearence count of consecutive chars:

```
public boolean isConsecutive(String stringToTest, int n) {
    int sumOfDifferences = 0;
    int lastTemp = 0;
    Boolean consecutive = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < stringToTest.length() - 1; i++) {
        // Whenever the difference is 1 or minues 1, add it to sumOfDifferences.
        // when sumOfDifferences= |max -1| -> break: consecutive!
        // when difference > 1 or difference < -1 : Reset sumOfDifferences.
        // when temp != lastTemp : Reset sumOfDifferences.
        int temp = stringToTest.charAt(i) - stringToTest.charAt(i + 1);

        if (temp != lastTemp) {
            // ASCI directon change. reset. Otherwhise 214 will be consecutive. when comparing for 3 characters. (sumOfdifference would be 2 (-1 + 3)
            sumOfDifferences = 0;
        }

        if (temp == 1 || temp == -1) {
            sumOfDifferences += temp;
        } else {
            // way off. reset.
            sumOfDifferences = 0;
        }

        // sumOfDiff == |n-1| ?
        if (sumOfDifferences == n - 1 || sumOfDifferences == ((n - 1) * -1)) {
            consecutive = true;
            break;
        }

        lastTemp = temp;
    }
    return consecutive;
}
```

The following tests have been positive:

```
@Test
public void testcons() {
    assertEquals(true, isConsecutive("89012", 3));
    assertEquals(true, isConsecutive("xyZabc", 3));
    assertEquals(false, isConsecutive("09283dgdDDf", 3));
    assertEquals(false, isConsecutive("AbCBa", 3));
    assertEquals(false, isConsecutive("1abC", 3));
    assertEquals(true, isConsecutive("DcbaZ", 3));

    assertEquals(true, isConsecutive("ab", 2));
    assertEquals(true, isConsecutive("abc", 3));
    assertEquals(true, isConsecutive("abcd", 4));
    assertEquals(true, isConsecutive("abcde", 5));
    assertEquals(true, isConsecutive("abcdef", 6));
}
```

This works for both: Numeric and Alphabetic Strings. (Even for alphanumeric, but if you don't want this, you can exclude them in advance)